# Symfony2 and Uploadify : security token is not kept

Tags: security, symfony, uploadify

I'm trying to make Symfony2 and Uploadify working together in a secured area.
(Uploadify is a flash/javascript component used to upload multiple files)

My uploadify component is working fine when the back-end script route is out of the secure area, but when in this area, I get a 302 HTTP error.

The log message is :

```
security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.)
```

While searching for an answer, I found that passing the *PHPSESSID* to the back-end script as a post parameter should work on "non-framework php" but with the Symfony Security Component, it seems that this script is not even reached.

Does anyone know if there is a way to send that token to the back-end script while keeping this script in the secure area ?

Answer (score 2):

After having a read around the Symfony website, it's possible that this solution may work (haven't tested it). In your security.yml file, change your `access_contol` config option to something like this...

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/path/to/flash_component, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Where /path/to/flash_component is the URL you are uploading to in Uploadify. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. I tried with your advice, but nothing. Have you found another solution? Thanks

Comment: You should clear your cache, and make sure that this access control rule is above all of the others